# How to apply validation when using InputFile in a custom component?

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, asp.net-core-8

As part of a migration to a design system, we are building our own components around the traditional Blazor components, with added markup and business logic that we can quickly re-use across our Blazor Server web application.

We've successfully managed to build components around the `InputText`, `InputDate` and `InputSelect` components, which inherit from `InputBase<T>`.  However, `InputFile` seems to work very differently to the others interally...

We are struggling with validation, and simply wish to bubble up any validation messages to the parent component, which seems to work fine when using other components.

We appreciate that [`InputFile` does not inherit from `InputBase<T>`](https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web/Forms/InputFile.cs,ef013b0c0d0db18c) and so works differently to the other input components, although I appreciate maybe our component should(?), in which case we don't know how to override `TryParseValueFromString()` because we cannot determine the appropriate type for the `string value` parameter (as I appreciate file input types are read-only in browsers, and so two-way binding likely isn't possible).

Currently validation is always failing regardless of whether a file is selected to upload.  It appears from research that validating this type of field is tricky and there's no definitive answers available to-date ([GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/18821) / [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66759760/blazor-webassembly-net-5-customized-component-with-files-validation-does-not)).

```
<div class="FileUploadComponent">
    <label>
        @Label
    </label>
    <div class="@ValidationCssClass">
        <InputFile OnChange="((e) => FileChanged(e))" accept="@string.Join(",", AllowedTypes)" />
    </div>

    @if (CascadedEditContext is not null && CascadedEditContext.GetValidationMessages().Any())
    {
        <div>
            @foreach (var message in CascadedEditContext.GetValidationMessages(inputFileId))
            {
                <div class="ValidationMessage">@message</div>
            }
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

Code behind:

```
public partial class FileUploadComponent
{
    [Parameter]
    public bool IsReadOnly { get; set; } = false;

    [CascadingParameter]
    private EditContext? CascadedEditContext { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public string? Label { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public Expression<Func<IBrowserFile>>? ValueExpression { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<IBrowserFile> ValueChanged { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public IBrowserFile? Value { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<InputFileChangeEventArgs> OnFileChanged { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public List<string> AllowedTypes { get; set; } = new();

    public string ValidationCssClass
    {
        get
        {
            return " " + (CascadedEditContext?.GetValidationMessages(inputFileId).Count() > 0 ? "invalid" : "valid");
        }
    }

    private FieldIdentifier inputFileId;

    private async void FileChanged(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        await OnFileChanged.InvokeAsync(e);
        CascadedEditContext?.NotifyFieldChanged(inputFileId);
    }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        if (ValueExpression is not null)
        {
            inputFileId = FieldIdentifier.Create(ValueExpression);
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: Maybe  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66759760/blazor-webassembly-net-5-customized-component-with-files-validation-does-not) is useful .

Comment: Somewhat thanks, but they're still left with a related issue of the validation state not being bubbled up to the parent component/page on submit, which is still part of this complex mystery!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [ValidationMessageStore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.forms.validationmessagestore?view=aspnetcore-7.0) to pass messages back to the parent `EditContext`.

And by subscribing to the `EditContext.OnValidationRequested`[docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.forms.editcontext.onvalidationrequested?view=aspnetcore-7.0) event you can listen to validation requested events e.g. when submit buttons on the form are clicked.

[Blazor Fiddle](https://blazorfiddle.com/s/mavwpr57)

```cs
private ValidationMessageStore ValidationMessageStore;

protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    if (CascadedEditContext is not null)
    {
        ValidationMessageStore = new ValidationMessageStore(CascadedEditContext);
        CascadedEditContext.OnValidationRequested += OnValidationRequested;
        if (ValueExpression is not null)
        {
            inputFileId = FieldIdentifier.Create(ValueExpression);
        }
    }
}

private void OnValidationRequested(object? sender, ValidationRequestedEventArgs e)
{
    if (CascadedEditContext is not null)
    {
        ValidateFile(Value);
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}
private bool ValidateFile(IBrowserFile file)
{
    ValidationMessageStore.Clear();
    if (file is null)
    {
        ValidationMessageStore.Add(inputFileId, $"Please select a file to upload");
        CascadedEditContext?.NotifyValidationStateChanged();
        return false;
    }

    bool anyValidationFailed = false;
    if (file.Size > MaxFileSizeInBytes)
    {
        ValidationMessageStore.Add(inputFileId, $"File size must be less than {MaxFileSizeInBytes} bytes.");
        anyValidationFailed = true;
    }

    if (!AllowedTypes.Contains(Path.GetExtension(file.Name)))
    {
        ValidationMessageStore.Add(inputFileId, "The selected file is not an accepted file type");
        anyValidationFailed = true;
    }
    if (anyValidationFailed)
    {
        CascadedEditContext?.NotifyValidationStateChanged();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
private async Task FileChanged(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
{
    var file = e.File;
    if (!ValidateFile(file))
    {
        return;
    }
    Value = file;
    await OnFileChanged.InvokeAsync(e);
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(inputFileId.FieldName))
    {
        CascadedEditContext?.NotifyFieldChanged(inputFileId);
    }
}
```

Comment: We amended it to allow multiple/single files but that seems pretty effective. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One of my colleagues appears to have found an answer, but **I will still gladly accept clarity** from more experienced developers.

It emerged that this method to raise the file changed event...

```
private async void FileChanged(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
{
    await OnFileChanged.InvokeAsync(e);
    CascadedEditContext?.NotifyFieldChanged(inputFileId);
}
```

...internally causes `StateHasChanged()` to be fired. This resets the file input control to not have a value, because this value cannot be set (bound back).  Therefore validation permanently fails.  This behaviour seems to be unique to the `input type=file` element which I understand has evolved over the years to protect users from abuse.

That sadly means (AFAIK) that validation has to be done manually and checked by the parent component (thus removing references to the cascading EditContext):

```
public partial class FileUploadComponent
{
    [Parameter]
    public string? Label { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public List<string> AllowedTypes { get; set; } = new();

    [Parameter]
    public bool AcceptsMultiple { get; set; } = false;

    [Parameter]
    public int MaxFileSizeInBytes { get; set; } = 2_097_152; // 2Mb default

    public List<string> ErrorMessages { get; set; } = new();

    private string ValidationOrFocusCssClass = "valid";

    public List<IBrowserFile> UploadedFiles { get; set; } = new();

    private void FileChanged(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        ValidationOrFocusCssClass = "valid";
        ErrorMessages = new();

        if (AcceptsMultiple && e.GetMultipleFiles != null || (!AcceptsMultiple && e.File != null))
        {
            UploadedFiles = new();

            if (AcceptsMultiple)
            {
                foreach (var f in e.GetMultipleFiles())
                {
                    UploadedFiles.Add(f);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (e.File is not null)
                {
                    UploadedFiles.Add(e.File);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public bool Validate()
    {
        if (UploadedFiles.Count == 0)
        {
            ErrorMessages.Add($"Please select {(AcceptsMultiple ? "at least one" : "a")} file to upload");
        }

        if (UploadedFiles.Any(x => x.Size > MaxFileSizeInBytes))
        {
            ErrorMessages.Add($"{(AcceptsMultiple ? "At least one" : "The")} selected file exceeds the size limit of {MaxFileSizeInBytes / 1024} Kb");
        }

        if (UploadedFiles.Any(x => !AllowedTypes.Contains(Path.GetExtension(x.Name))))
        {
            ErrorMessages.Add($"{(AcceptsMultiple ? "At least one" : "The")} selected file is not an accepted file type");
        }

        ValidationOrFocusCssClass = ErrorMessages.Count != 0 ? "invalid" : "valid";

        return ErrorMessages.Count == 0;
    }
}
```

Parent component HTML:

```
<FileUploadComponent AllowedTypes="AllowedFileTypes" @ref=@MyFileUploadComponent MaxFileSizeInBytes=@MaxProfileFileSizeBytes AcceptsMultiple=false/>
```

Parent component code:

```
protected async Task ProfilePhotoUploaded()
{
    if (!MyFileUploadComponent.Validate()) {
        return;
    }

    try
    {
        foreach (var uploadedFile in MyFileUploadComponent.UploadedFiles)
        {
            var fileName = $"test.jpg";
            var tempFolder = Path.GetTempPath();
            var workingFilePath = Path.Combine(tempFolder, fileName);
            await using FileStream fs = new(workingFilePath, FileMode.Create);
            await uploadedFile.OpenReadStream().CopyToAsync(fs);
        }
        Feedback = "Photo uploaded";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Feedback = ex.Message;
    }

    StateHasChanged();
}
```